# Using a Repeater to display time punch data by day

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new, so I'm sure I'm completely screwing up how to do this. I apologize in advance...

I have a Repeater that output time card punches for each day. The data comes from a database with the structure shown below. When I output the data in the Repeater, it just keeps adding the data

Is there a way to output the following data:

```
SELECT PunchId, PunchIn, PunchOut, PunchDay, WeekEnding
FROM   TimePunches
WHERE  WeekEnding = @WeekEnding

PunchId   PunchIn   PunchOut   PunchDay   WeekEnding
 1         09:00 AM  03:35 PM   2          06/07/2014
 2         08:34 AM  09:11 AM   4          06/07/2014
 3         09:11 AM  09:20 AM   4          06/07/2014
 4         09:20 AM  05:20 PM   4          06/07/2014
 5         08:33 AM  11:46 AM   5          06/07/2014
 6         12:12 PM  05:19 PM   5          06/07/2014
 7         05:25 PM  06:19 PM   5          06/07/2014
 8         07:25 PM  09:01 PM   5          06/07/2014
```

to display as:

```
Sun       Mon       Tue       Wed       Thr       Fri       Sat
          09:00 AM            08:34 AM  08:33 AM
          03:35 PM            09:11 AM  11:46 AM
                              09:11 AM  12:12 PM
                              09:20 AM  05:19 PM
                              09:20 AM  05:25 PM
                              05:10 PM  06:19 PM
                                        07:25 PM
                                        09:01 PM
```

Currently it's doing this which is bad

```
Sun       Mon       Tue       Wed       Thr       Fri       Sat
          09:00 AM
          03:35 PM
                              08:34 AM
                              09:11 AM
                              09:11 AM
                              09:20 AM
                              09:20 AM
                              05:10 PM
                                        08:33 AM
                                        11:46 AM
                                        12:12 PM
                                        05:19 PM
                                        05:25 PM
                                        06:19 PM
                                        07:25 PM
                                        09:01 PM
```

I'm pretty sure there's a fairly simple way to do it and I'm just over thinking it. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  [1] Sun, [2] Mon, [3] Tue, [4] Wed, [5] Thr, [6] Fri, [7] Sat
FROM (
   SELECT
     PunchTime,
     PunchDay,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PunchDay ORDER BY PunchTime) RowNumber
   FROM @t
   UNPIVOT(PunchTime for PunchType in (PunchIn,PunchOut) ) t1
) t2
PIVOT(MAX(PunchTime) FOR PunchDay IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]) ) t3
```